# Debug Hadoop jobs inside IntelliJ: "class file for org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf not found"

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, intellij-idea

I'm fairly new to Java and have never used Cascading, so thought I'd work through the [Cascading tutorial](http://docs.cascading.org/tutorials/etl-log/part1.html) before trying something more ambitious. I was able to build and run a shaded jar at the command line (see [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/alexwoolford/6b033c95e73f84afd7d3)), i.e. it's executable like this:

```
hadoop jar ./target/cascading-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /logs/NASA_access_log_Aug95.txt /output
```

The command line version lacks all the bells & whistles of an IDE, and so I'd like to run it within IntelliJ where it'll be easier to debug. As it stands, if I just run the class within IntelliJ it complains:

```
class file for org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf not found
```

I'm wondering what the 'Edit Configurations' settings look like to do the equivalent of `hadoop jar ...`, and to pass in the two arguments (hdfs paths).